# Django get_absolute_url() fails in Generic Views due to self.object being None

Tags: django, view, django-class-based-views

so I've been running into this issue where my class based edit (CreateView and UpdateView) views were failing to redirect consistently on a random selection of my models, saying that get_absolute_url is not defined even though it is for those models. I did some debugging in the actual class based view and I realized that it's because in those in the get_success_url() method, the self.object is None, but running self.get_object() returns the correct object. I'm curious as to why self.object would be none but self.get_object would work in this case and I kind of know how I could hack out a solution to this, but I feel like I probably shouldn't have to so that probably means part of my process is incorrect, although I don't know what since I'm writing simple models, defining get_absolute_url and setting model and form_class in my CreateView and UpdateViews. Has anyone run into this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I realized just now that the issue was that I had overriden save in my ModelForm for those classes and although I had saved the objects I was not returning them. Returning them solved the problem. Taking a look into form_valid of ModelFormMixin showed me the solution.